# Salesforce Apex, traversing XML with tags with the same name

Tags: xml, salesforce, apex

I am struggling to traverse some XML. there are several  s
and I must read in every one to get the children from them. 
My current code will only read in the first  record.
I should have 5 records, but get the first one 6 times.
My for loop is obviously not working and not setting the fields each time.
I have tried to look at the debug log, but returns and empty screen.

```
Dom.XmlNode lien_data_sectList  = uspprlien_data.getChildElement('LIEN_DATA_SECT',  null); 

for(Dom.XmlNode lien_data_sects :uspprlien_data.getChildElements()) {
    Dom.XmlNode lien_data_sect = uspprlien_data.getChildElement('LIEN_DATA_SECT',  null);

    //LIEN_STAT__c    Lien Status               

    Dom.Xmlnode lienStats = lien_data_sect.getChildElement('LIEN_STAT',  null);
    if (lienStats  != null) {
        P_record.LIEN_STAT__c = lienStats.getText();
        system.debug(P_record.LIEN_STAT__c);
    }

    //LIEN_AMT__c Lien Amount
    Dom.Xmlnode lienAmts = lien_data_sect.getChildElement('LIEN_AMT',  null);

    if (lienAmts != null) {
        P_record.LIEN_AMT__c = lienAmts.getText();
        P_record.Lien_Amount_Final__c = Decimal.valueOf(P_record.LIEN_AMT__c);
    }

    m_PRLiens.add(P_record);
} //LIEN_DATA_SECT loop end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already looping through the children of the parent node, there's no need to get it by name.

```
Dom.XmlNode lien_data_sectList  = uspprlien_data.getChildElement('LIEN_DATA_SECT',  null); 
for(Dom.XmlNode lien_data_sect :uspprlien_data.getChildElements()) {
//LIEN_STAT__c    Lien Status               
Dom.Xmlnode lienStats = lien_data_sect.getChildElement('LIEN_STAT',  null);
if (lienStats  != null) {
    P_record.LIEN_STAT__c = lienStats.getText();
    system.debug(P_record.LIEN_STAT__c);
}

//LIEN_AMT__c Lien Amount
Dom.Xmlnode lienAmts = lien_data_sect.getChildElement('LIEN_AMT',  null);

if (lienAmts != null) {
    P_record.LIEN_AMT__c = lienAmts.getText();
    P_record.Lien_Amount_Final__c = Decimal.valueOf(P_record.LIEN_AMT__c);
}

m_PRLiens.add(P_record);
} //LIEN_DATA_SECT loop endenter code here
```